# Replace a word from source field -> {{.....}} in target field in Anki use Javascripts

Tags: javascript, replace, anki

Does anyone know Anki?

I have two fields "Kanji" and "Examples" and I insert these into Front Card.

```html
<div class ="Kanji">{{Kanji}}</div>

<div class = "Examples">{{Examples}}</div>
```

with `{{Kanji}}` is `早` and `{{Examples}}` is `早い(はやい): (1) fast; quick; hasty; brisk`.

Now I want to replace exactly the Kanji word from `{{Kanji}}` in `{{Examples}}` to {{.....}} (like cloze card).

Please help me and thank you for your advance.

Ps: I think Anki doesn't fully support Javascript. So you should write more simple.